# Does my graphics engine code follow good conventions?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a 2d graphics engine. I am somewhat new to JavaScript and have been winging this project. So far it creates a background (a tilemap made of smaller images in a grid) and sprites ( a small image 
with a higher z index). I ommited my test code, as I didn't care for that to be reviewed, but if it needs to be included I can add it.

I am looking for best practice advice for javascript or in general. One specific question is: Are the OLNs (sprites and tilemap) used correctly or should something else be used?

js:

```
'use strict';

const TILEMAPSIZE = 160; // Total number of tiles displayed. Must be a multiple of TILECOLUMNS.
const TILECOLUMNS = 16; // Number of columns

let tileSet = []; // Set of all tiles to be used
let tilemapList = []; // The order in which the tiles are used via references to elements in tileSet
let spriteSet = []; // Set of all sprites to be used

loadResources(); 

let sprites = (function (){
    function createSprites(spritesList) {
        let spriteCount = 0;
        spritesList.forEach(x => {
            let sprite = document.createElement('img');
            sprite.src = x;
            sprite.className = "sprites";
            sprite.id = "sprite" + spriteCount;
            sprite.style.visibility = "hidden";
            ++spriteCount;
            document.getElementById("window").appendChild(sprite);
        });
    }

    function show(index) {
        const spriteStyle = document.getElementById("sprite" + index).style
        spriteStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hide(index) {
        spriteStyle = document.getElementById("sprite" + index).style
        spriteStyle.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function reflectY(spriteIndex) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        const transform = document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform;
        if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){ 
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
    }

    function reflectX(spriteIndex) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        const transform = document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform;
        if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
    }

    function reflect(spriteIndex, dX, dY) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        if (dX === true && dY === true){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (dX === true && dY === false){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
        else if (dX === false && dY === true){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
        else if (dX === false && dY === false){
            document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
    }

    function translate(spriteIndex, dX, dY) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        const posLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById(sprite).style.left.slice(0, -2)) + dX;
        const posTop = parseInt(document.getElementById(sprite).style.top.slice(0, -2)) + dY;
        document.getElementById(sprite).style.left = posLeft + "px";
        document.getElementById(sprite).style.top = posTop + "px";
    }

    function setPosition(spriteIndex, dX, dY) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        document.getElementById(sprite).style.left = dX +"px";
        document.getElementById(sprite).style.top = dY + "px";
    }

    function getPosition(spriteIndex) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        return {
            x: parseInt(document.getElementById(sprite).style.left.slice(0, -2)),
            y: parseInt(document.getElementById(sprite).style.top.slice(0, -2))
        };
    }

    function getOrientation(spriteIndex) {
        const sprite = "sprite" + spriteIndex;
        const transform = document.getElementById(sprite).style.transform;
        let pair = {};

        if (transform === "scale(1)"){
            pair = {x: 1, y: 1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            pair = {x: -1, y: -1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            pair = {x: 1, y: -1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){
            pair = {x: -1, y: 1};
        }
        else {
            pair = {x: 0, y: 0};
        }
        return pair;
    }

    return{
        setPosition: setPosition,
        getPosition: getPosition,
        getOrientation: getOrientation,
        translate: translate,
        reflect: reflect,
        reflectX: reflectX,
        reflectY: reflectY,
        createSprites: createSprites,
        show: show,
        hide: hide
    };
}())

let tilemap = (function (){
    function create(){
        // create the tile map
        for (let i = 0; i < TILEMAPSIZE; ++i){
            let tile = document.createElement('div');
            tile.className = "tile";
            tile.id = "tile" + i;
            document.getElementById("tilemap").appendChild(tile);
        };            
        // set the number of columns
        let value = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < TILECOLUMNS; ++i){
            value += "auto ";
        }
        document.getElementById("tilemap").style.gridTemplateColumns = value;
        // insert images
        let index = 0;
        tilemapList.forEach(x => {
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = x;
            img.className = "tileImage";
            document.getElementById("tile" + index).appendChild(img);
            ++index; 
        })
    }

    function show() {
        spriteStyle = document.getElementById("tilemap").style
        spriteStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hide() {
        spriteStyle = document.getElementById("tilemap").style
        spriteStyle.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function translate(dX, dY) {
        const posLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("viewport").style.left.slice(0, -2)) + dX;
        const posTop = parseInt(document.getElementById("viewport").style.top.slice(0, -2)) + dY;
        document.getElementById("viewport").style.left = posLeft + "px";
        document.getElementById("viewport").style.top = posTop + "px";
    }

    function setPosition(dX, dY) {
        document.getElementById("viewport").style.top = dY + "px";
        document.getElementById("viewport").style.left = dX + "px";
    }

    function getPosition() {
        return {
            x: parseInt(document.getElementById("viewport").style.left.slice(0, -2)),
            y: parseInt(document.getElementById("viewport").style.top.slice(0, -2))
        };
    }

    return{
        setPosition: setPosition,
        getPosition: getPosition,
        translate: translate,
        show: show,
        hide: hide,
        create: create};   
}())

tilemap.setPosition(0, 0);
tilemap.create();

sprites.createSprites(spriteSet);
sprites.setPosition(0, 235, 240);
sprites.show(0); 

function loadResources(){
    const img1 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/ferns.jpg';
    const img2 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/tulips.jpg';
    const img3 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/water.jpg';

    const sprite0 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/daffodil.jpg';    
    const sprite1 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/eagle.jpg';    

    spriteSet = [sprite0, sprite1];
    tileSet = [img1, img2, img3];
    tilemapList = [tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0], tileSet[0] , tileSet[2], tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] , tileSet[2], tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] , tileSet[2]];    
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="window">
        <div id="viewport">
            <div id ="tilemap">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

````
:root {
    --TILESIZE: 50px; /* Size of tiles */
    --SPRITESIZE: 50px; /* Size of sprites */
    --WINDOWIDTH: 650px;
    --WINDOWHEIGHT: 500px;
    --WINDOWBACKGROUND: white;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

#window {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: var(--WINDOWIDTH);
    height: var(--WINDOWHEIGHT);
    background: var(--WINDOWBACKGROUND);
}

#viewport {
    position: absolute;
}

#tilemap {
  display: grid;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tile {
  text-align: center;
}

.tileImage {
    height: var(--TILESIZE);
    width:  var(--TILESIZE);
}

.sprites {
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--SPRITESIZE);
    width:  var(--SPRITESIZE);
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of improvements you can make.

Reassigning global variables so that a particular function can proceed to use them (`spriteSet`, `tileSet`, `tilemapList`) is pretty strange. It would make a lot more sense if these were only passed as arguments to the functions that need them instead. In fact, since the `tileSet` isn't being used anywhere except inside `loadResources`, that can be made completely local:

```
const { spriteSet, tilemapList } = loadResources();
tilemap.setPosition(0, 0);
tilemap.create(tilemapList);

sprites.createSprites(spriteSet);
```

Always declare variables [with `const` when possible](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) - you don't intend to reassign the `sprites` or the `tilemap` object, right? There are a few variables like this - consider using a linter to prompt you to fix these sorts of potential mistakes automatically.

The `tilemapList` definition is repetitive and difficult to read:

```
const tilemapList = [tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1] , tileSet[1] , tileSet[0] ,tileSet[2], tileSet[1]
```

Consider defining the layout with a single string instead, where each cell (numeric, indicating the index of the tile in the `tileSet`) is separated by a space (or few) or newlines, which gets parsed into the array above afterwards - this way, it'll be far more readable and less prone to copy/paste bugs or the like:

```
const tiles = `
2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0
2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 1
`
.trim()
.split(/\s+/)
.map(index => tileSet[index]);
```

Numeric-indexed IDs are never a good idea - IDs are for elements that are *absolutely unique* in a document, and they create global variables, unfortunately. If you want a way to select the `n`th sprite in the tilemap, just select the `n`th child of the tilemap:

```
tilemap.children[i]
```

You might put the children into an array, and have the array in a closure or on an instance so it's easily accessible by all methods. (See snippet below for an example)

Having `sprites` for the main sprite maker object isn't as precise as it could be. I'd expect a variable named `sprites` to be an array-like collection of `sprite` objects. Maybe call the main sprite maker `SpritesMaker` instead? You can also use a class instead of an IIFE in order to have the children as a property of the instance, as mentioned above.

You frequently select elements over and over again:

```
spritesList.forEach(x => {
  // do stuff
  document.getElementById("window").appendChild(sprite);
```

Consider selecting the element *once* instead, rather than having to go through the DOM to find the element again each time:

```
const win = document.getElementById("window");
spritesList.forEach(x => {
  // do stuff
  win.appendChild(sprite);
```

You have a lot of places where the above pattern can make the code a lot cleaner - instead of repeating `document.getElementById(x)` multiple times, do `const someElement = document.getElementById(x)` and then repeat `someElement` instead. Nearly all of the functions in both the big `sprites` object and the `tilemap` object can be significantly improved with this technique.

But `window` is a *very* weird ID - it's very easily confused with `window`, the global object. Consider using something else, like `main`. You might even avoid IDs altogether, since every element with an ID creates an additional global variable of that name, which can occasionally result in confusing weird bugs.

You have

```
spritesList.forEach(x => {
```

`x` isn't very descriptive at all. Best to call a variable what it represents, maybe `srcStr`.

Since you're appending each sprite to the `.main`, you may avoid having to set a class name on each sprite element by using the `.main > img` in your CSS instead.

You have

```
if (dX === true && dY === true){
    style.transform = "scale(1)";
} else if (dX === true && dY === false){
```

You may use simple truthy/falsey tests instead if you wish:

```
if (dX && dY){
    style.transform = "scale(1)";
}
else if (dX && !dY){
    style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
}
```

Rather than frequently checking and reassigning with

```
let pair = {};

if (transform === "scale(1)"){
    pair = {x: 1, y: 1};
}
else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
    pair = {x: -1, y: -1};
}
// etc
return pair;
```

You might consider just returning the object instead:

```
if (transform === "scale(1)"){
    return {x: 1, y: 1};
}
else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
    return {x: -1, y: -1};
}
```

If you *do* want to keep using the IIFE, note that you may use shorthand properties in ES2015, and you're using ES2015 syntax already. The below:

```
return{
    setPosition: setPosition,
    getPosition: getPosition,
    getOrientation: getOrientation,
    // ...
```

simplifies to

```
return {
    setPosition,
    getPosition,
    getOrientation,
    // ...
```

All together:

```js
'use strict';

const TILEMAPSIZE = 160; // Total number of tiles displayed. Must be a multiple of TILECOLUMNS.
const TILECOLUMNS = 16; // Number of columns

class SpritesMaker {
    constructor(spritesList) {
        const main = document.querySelector('.main');
        this.sprites = spritesList.map(srcStr => {
            const sprite = document.createElement('img');
            sprite.src = srcStr;
            main.appendChild(sprite);
            return sprite;
        });
    }

    show(index) {
        this.sprites[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    hide(index) {
        this.sprites[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    reflectY(index) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        const transform = style.transform;
        if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){ 
            style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
        else {
            style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
    }

    reflectY(index) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        const transform = style.transform;
        if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){
            style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
        else {
            style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
    }

    reflect(index, dX, dY) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        if (dX && dY){
            style.transform = "scale(1)";
        }
        else if (dX && !dY){
            style.transform = "scale(1, -1)";
        }
        else if (!dX && dY){
            style.transform = "scale(-1, 1)";
        }
        else if (!dX && !dY){
            style.transform = "scale(-1)";
        }
    }

    translate(index, dX, dY) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        const posLeft = Number(style.left.slice(0, -2)) + dX;
        const posTop = Number(style.top.slice(0, -2)) + dY;
        style.left = posLeft + "px";
        style.top = posTop + "px";
    }

    setPosition(index, dX, dY) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        style.left = dX +"px";
        style.top = dY + "px";
    }

    getPosition(spriteIndex) {
        const { style } = this.sprites[index];
        return {
            x: Number(style.left.slice(0, -2)),
            y: Number(style.top.slice(0, -2))
        };
    }

    getOrientation(index) {
        const { transform } = this.sprites[index].transform;
        if (transform === "scale(1)"){
            return {x: 1, y: 1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1)"){
            return {x: -1, y: -1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(1, -1)"){
            return {x: 1, y: -1};
        }
        else if (transform === "scale(-1, 1)"){
            return {x: -1, y: 1};
        }
        else {
            return {x: 0, y: 0};
        }
    }
}

class TileMap {
    constructor(tilemapList){
        this.viewport = document.querySelector('.viewport');
        this.tilemapDiv = document.querySelector('.tilemap');
        // set the number of columns
        let value = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < TILECOLUMNS; ++i){
            value += "auto ";
        }
        this.tilemapDiv.style.gridTemplateColumns = value;
        
        // create the tile map
        this.tiles = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < TILEMAPSIZE; ++i){
            this.tiles.push(this.tilemapDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div')));
        };            
        
        // insert images
        tilemapList.forEach((src, i) => {
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = src;
            this.tiles[i].appendChild(img);
        })
    }

    show() {
        this.tilemapDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    hide() {
        this.tilemapDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    translate(dX, dY) {
        const { style } = this.viewport;
        const posLeft = Number(style.left.slice(0, -2)) + dX;
        const posTop = Number(style.top.slice(0, -2)) + dY;
        style.left = posLeft + "px";
        style.top = posTop + "px";
    }

    setPosition(dX, dY) {
        const { style } = this.viewport;
        style.top = dY + "px";
        style.left = dX + "px";
    }

    getPosition() {
        const { left, top } = this.viewport.style;
        return {
            x: style.left.slice(0, -2),
            y: style.top.slice(0, -2)
        };
    }
}

const { spriteSet, tilemapList } = loadResources();
const tileMap = new TileMap(tilemapList);
tileMap.setPosition(0, 0);

const fernsTulipsSprites = new SpritesMaker(spriteSet);
fernsTulipsSprites.setPosition(0, 235, 240);
fernsTulipsSprites.show(0); 

function loadResources(){
    const img1 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/ferns.jpg';
    const img2 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/tulips.jpg';
    const img3 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/water.jpg';

    const sprite0 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/daffodil.jpg';    
    const sprite1 = 'https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/eagle.jpg';    

    const spriteSet = [sprite0, sprite1];
    const tileSet = [img1, img2, img3];
    const tilemapList = `
    2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 
    2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 
    2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 
    2 1 1 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 
    1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 
    1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 
    1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 2 1 1 0 2 
    1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 
    1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 
    1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2
    `
      .trim()
      .split(/\s+/)
      .map(index => tileSet[index]);
    return { spriteSet, tilemapList };
}
```

```css
:root {
  --TILESIZE: 50px;
  /* Size of tiles */
  --SPRITESIZE: 50px;
  /* Size of sprites */
  --WINDOWIDTH: 650px;
  --WINDOWHEIGHT: 500px;
  --WINDOWBACKGROUND: white;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.window {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--WINDOWIDTH);
  height: var(--WINDOWHEIGHT);
  background: var(--WINDOWBACKGROUND);
}

.viewport {
  position: absolute;
}

.tilemap {
  display: grid;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tilemap > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.tilemap > div > img {
  height: var(--TILESIZE);
  width: var(--TILESIZE);
}

.main > img {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--SPRITESIZE);
  width: var(--SPRITESIZE);
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="tilemap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I'm still chewing through this, but you made some classes so we can use ` tilemap.children[i] ` but that returns `TypeError: "tileMap.children is undefined"`. (If `i` is set and `tilemap` is `tileMap`)

Comment: Also, are classes

Comment: If you do `const tileMap = new TileMap(tilemapList);`, you have an instance of the object as `tileMap`, not the `tilemap` *element* - better to decrease these sorts of name collisions when possible. In the code in the snippet, I assigned the element to the `tilemapDiv` property of the instance, so if you want to get to the element, you have to access that property of the instance. The instance doesn't have a `children` property.

Comment: Classes are generally for when you want to tie together persistent *data* (here, HTML elements) with methods that do stuff with that data (here, modify the elements). Classes are very suited for the job here.

Comment: Sorry my comment got submitted early by accident, I thought that classes wasn't very JavaScripty, So I was avoiding them. Plus they didn't need to keep track of state, so I thought the IIFE(i thought it was called OLN?) was more appropriate.

Comment: Additionally, the reason we switched to classes ended up not even existing if the tilemapDiv doesn't have children.

Comment: Never heard of OLN. If you mean object literal, that'd be *just* the declaration of an object literal, `const obj = { prop: 'val' }`. An immediately-invoked function expression which returns an object is different. `const obj = (() => { /* do lots of stuff */ return { prop: 'val' }; })();`

Comment: Sure, classes are often overused in Javascript, IMO. At least in my experience, they're rarely the right tool for the job - but sometimes, they are, and this is a decent example: if you have instance variables, no need for (smelly) globals. (it also allows you to easily extend the script to create *multiple* grids/sprites/etc, if you ever wanted to).

Comment: Oh I was just trying to do classes the "JavaScript way" and ended up with the IIF,E but somewhere someone called it OLN - object literal notation.

Comment: *they didn't need to keep track of state* The elements tied to the methods *are* state, pretty much - you have to keep persistent track of them while calling the different functions that do stuff with them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just have one last question, is `tileMap.tiles[0].innerHTML = "<img src=\"https://georgec0stanza.github.io/2DgraphicsEngine/images/eagle.jpg\">"` an elegant way of changing a tile in the tilemap? I tried the `tilemapDiv.children` but that doesn't change anything in the document.

Comment: I'd prefer to change the `src` of the image. `this.tiles[0].children[0].src = 'newSrc'`. `this.tilemapDiv.children` will give you the same sort of collection as `tileMap.tiles`

Comment: yeah but that gives me `TypeError: 0 is read-only` and I tried changing all the `const`s to `let`s to no avail.

Comment: Works just fine here https://jsfiddle.net/9ah7rdw0/

Comment: I missed the `.src`... lol I feel dumb!